# How to union two exploded results when one is empty?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

env: spark2.4.5

My spark sql:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM table_0
    LATERAL VIEW explode(table_0.Array_0) exploded_a_values AS A
UNION
SELECT B.*
FROM table_0
    LATERAL VIEW explode(table_0.Array_1) exploded_a_values AS B
```

The explode structure A and B have the same schema. Error occurs when one of them is empty:

```
Can only star expand struct data types. Attribute: `ArrayBuffer)`;
```

Notice that elements in array is type of struct. My purpose is to pick out distinct elements in different array.

So how can I handles such empty case? I would be very grateful if you could give me some suggestion.

Comment: please accept + upvote if my ans helps you

Answer (score 1):

when you explode an array using `explode(table_0.Array_0) exploded_a_values AS A`,

Here

- `exploded_a_values` becomes `table` and
- `A` becomes the column representing `exploded column`

Thus, you can't call `A.*` on that but of course you can call `exploded_a_values.*`

So your modified query will look like as below-

### 1. Read the input

```scala
     val table_0 =  spark.range(1, 5)
      .withColumn("Array_0", array(lit(1), lit(2)))
      .withColumn("Array_1", array(lit(null).cast(IntegerType)))
    table_0.show(false)
    table_0.printSchema()
```

Ouput-

```
+---+-------+-------+
|id |Array_0|Array_1|
+---+-------+-------+
|1  |[1, 2] |[]     |
|2  |[1, 2] |[]     |
|3  |[1, 2] |[]     |
|4  |[1, 2] |[]     |
+---+-------+-------+

root
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |-- Array_0: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
 |-- Array_1: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

### 2. Run Union query

```scala
    table_0.createOrReplaceTempView("table_0")

    val processed = spark.sql(
      """
        |SELECT exploded_a_values.*, table_0.id
        |FROM table_0
        |    LATERAL VIEW explode(table_0.Array_0) exploded_a_values AS A
        |UNION
        |SELECT exploded_b_values.*, table_0.id
        |FROM table_0
        |    LATERAL VIEW explode(table_0.Array_1) exploded_b_values AS B
      """.stripMargin)
    processed.show(false)
    processed.printSchema()
```

Output-

```
+----+---+
|A   |id |
+----+---+
|2   |2  |
|2   |4  |
|null|2  |
|null|4  |
|1   |1  |
|2   |1  |
|1   |2  |
|1   |3  |
|2   |3  |
|1   |4  |
|null|1  |
|null|3  |
+----+---+

root
 |-- A: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
```

> Note: Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types.

### Edit-1 (As per comments)

Tried with `Array<struct>`, the same query worked well for me-
Here is the result:

```
+------+---+
|A     |id |
+------+---+
|[a, 2]|1  |
|[a, 2]|2  |
|[a, 2]|4  |
|null  |2  |
|null  |4  |
|[a, 2]|3  |
|null  |1  |
|null  |3  |
+------+---+

root
 |-- A: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- f1: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- f2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- id: long (nullable = false)
```

For full example, please refer - [this gist](https://gist.github.com/skale1990/26448400c7655543f9e1177dd17763bf#file-problemsolvertest-scala-L485)

Comment: Element in your array is integer, but struct in my scenario. I tried your answer and it reports with error: Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. string <> struct<...>...

Comment: My purpose is to select the distinct struct element in two array.

Comment: what is the schema for `array<struct<?>>` here can you tell me the question mark

Comment: Also It would be better if you can provide schema for `table_0`

Comment: The original struct is too complicated and any struct can be applied to this question.

Comment: does `Array_0` and `Array_1` has same struct? actually to union the 2 dfs, we need to have column with same name and its types

Comment: Yep, they have the elements with same struct, but sometimes one of them is empty, and this is what I can't handle with.